# What's the correct pronunciation of the indefinite article "a"?

Tags: pronunciation

I have noticed watching series, that some characters, or even the voice of my translator speaks the letter "a" with two different sounds when it's in a sentence.

For example:

It's correct to say "ae bus" or "ah" bus? (a bus)?

I'm struggling to get the pattern, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Some words have two different pronunciations even though the spelling is the same. *Either*, *data*, *the*. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, the right way to spell "a" is "a."

Comment: You mean the way that it sounds when we are saying the alphabet?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what you mean by "spell the letter." Spelling refers to the written form "a." Do you mean pronunciation or speech?

Comment: Are you referring to the letter "A", or to the indefinite article _a/an_? And are you referring to how something is pronounced, spelled, or punctuated? Examples of what you mean are more useful than attempts at description.

Comment: Pronunciation. I'm sorry if I said something wrong. I'm not native.

Comment: My doubt is about the pronunciation of the article "a" in a conversation, because I'm used to listen people say with two different sounds (ae and ah)  I thought saying "letter" it would fit too.

Comment: @VickiSant'Anna Do you know what "bay" sounds like? If you speak Spanish, "a" sounds like "e".

Comment: Yes! And also, I'm Brazilian, but I got it ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why everyone is confusing the issue so much.

In ordinary conversation, the indefinite article *a* is pronounced as an indeterminate vowel (the [schwa](https://pronunciationstudio.com/schwa-pronunciation-guide/) ). I assume that's what you mean by *ah*.

Occasionally, if you want to put stress on the indefinite article (perhaps to tell someone to use *a* and not *the*), you might pronounce it like the letter A (your *ae*).

Comment: Thank you much! This issue was a little bit hazy for me, but fortunately you were able to understand what was my doubt! Really helpful 

Answer (score 0):

It's better to say a it is more complex and brief at this point.

Comment: It's was hard to express my doubt, because the sound of "a" to me it's already different. I'm not a native :c

Comment: I get you no worries Hakuna Matata.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  It says that something is both more complex and more brief than something else, but I don't understand what either of the compared things is.  Can you clarify ?

Comment: My doubt consist in pronounce the letter "a" with the correct pronunciation, but I have noticed that in the mostly conversations the way people say "a" it's not the same way as we say the letter "a" when saying the Alphabet. I know, it's a complicated question hehehe, but I desperatelly want to understand this.

Comment: Ok for me in my POV it is "ae" and "ah" because of how they both can similar or alike. In some cases, this can mean how they are alike or different from each other.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I think your answer might have made sense with a previous version of the question but now it doesn’t match and it has been flagged as "poor quality". Good answer usually contain some quoted reference so they are clearly not just opinion based. If you still want to provide an answer, I suggest you write a new, clearer answer rather that edit this one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/363446)